# Class variables not updating as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create class variables that are dependent on other class variables, and I am having some problems. I will explain with code:

A simple example of the code structure is provided below:

```
class strategy():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'AAPL':140, 'TSLA':225, 'GOOG':175}
        
        self.insights = dict(filter(lambda x : x[1] > 150, self.data.items()))
```

As a test, I run the script and then run the following commands with the shown results:

```
s = strategy()

s.data
% {'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}

s.insights
% {'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}
```

At this point everything has worked as expected. The self.insights variable has been populated using self.data. However, if I update the data variable, the insights do not change:

```
s.data['GME'] = 500

s.data
% {'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175, 'GME': 500}

s.insights
% {'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}
```

As you can see, the self.data variable updates successfully, but the self.insights variable does not change. It was my understanding that if I define a variable as a function of another variable, they will update together. Is this not the case?

Comment: `self.insights` is set when `__init__()` is run. After that, it retains its value. You'll need a function call to update `self.insights`.

Comment: But the answer to your question is: yes, this is not the case. Your understanding is incorrect, since it would require calling the function explicitly.

Comment: (I think there are other, more dynamic languages that more or less do have this behaviour.)

Comment: It's a bit of advanced concept, but this is a perfect use for descriptors (getters/setters), where updating `data` would automatically regenerate `insights`.

Comment: you could just use the [property decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: My goal with this process is to define an object with many attributes that are always updated without the need to call an update method. For example, I want self.insights to be directly dependent on self.data; self.insights should reflect any changes in self.data in real time. I am trying to avoid an event-driven system as I think moving around data in messages is messy and non-pythonic.

Comment: "However, if I update the data variable, the insights do not change" Of course. These two variables are referring to two different `dict` objects. That is what you did when you wrote `self.insights = dict(filter(lambda x : x[1] > 150, self.data.items()))`. You created a new dict using the `dict` constructor. You assigned that new dict to the attribute `self.insights`.

Comment: Minor side-note: `dict(filter(lambda x : x[1] > 150, self.data.items()))` is fairly unpythonic. A simple dict comprehension is shorter, easier to read, and likely faster to boot: `{k: v for k, v in self.data.items() if v > 150}` does the exact same thing more cleanly.

Comment: "I define a variable as a function of another variable, they will update together. Is this not the case?" That is not correct, strictly speaking. Variables, (or "attributes" when they exist on objects) are just *names that refer to objects*. If both names are referring to the same object, then they will of course look the same. Otherwise, they are two independent objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin `@property` decorator to define a function to get a value which updates based on other class variables:

```py
class Strategy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"AAPL": 140, "TSLA": 225, "GOOG": 175}
    @property
    def insights(self):
        return {k: v for k, v in self.data.items() if v > 150}

    
s = Strategy()
s.data
>> {'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}
s.insights
>> {'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}
s.data["GME"] = 500
s.data
>> {'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175, 'GME': 500}
s.insights  # Updated successfully 
>> {'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175, 'GME': 500}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your filtering method is much nicer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Guidance from sj95126 and Robin Zigmond resulted in the following code that works as originally desired:

```
class strategy():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'AAPL':140, 'TSLA':225, 'GOOG':175}
    
    @property
    def insights(self):
        return dict(filter(lambda x : x[1] > 150, self.data.items()))
```

The getter/setter functionality of the @property decorator is used here with the following results:

```
>>> s = strategy()

>>> s.data
{'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}

>>> s.insights
{'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175}

>>> s.data['GME'] = 500

>>> s.data
{'AAPL': 140, 'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175, 'GME': 500}

>>> s.insights
{'TSLA': 225, 'GOOG': 175, 'GME': 500}
```

As you can see, self.insights updates as expected and there is no excess data transfer or redundant data.

Comment: Note: This will recreate the `dict` from `insights` on *every* access, even if `data` hasn't changed. There's no good way to avoid this (any form of caching you introduce would risk other problems, like a caller modifying `insights` and changing the cached value), but it does mean you need to be sure to not to access `s.insights` too often (possibly caching it yourself, if you can live with it being stale for however long you preserve the cache).

Comment: The self.insights property will be called once per time step (which needs to be done anyways as that is the update frequency for self.data). Functions that use self.insights will store the current state in a variable so that it does not need to be called many times in the same function. The goal for this approach is to avoid an event-driven system. I don't think stateless is the correct term, but that's the best way I can describe my goal.